# Reset GIMP User interface only

Tags: 11.10, gimp

I have messed with GIMP UI and I cannot find some buttons/tabs. I s there a way to reset everything to default without loosing other data? Sorry if it is answered somewhere, search button didn't help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ignore the previous commenter and delete only ~/.gimp-x.x/dockrc. That will bring back defaults for just dockable dialogs.

Removing all of ~/.gimp-x.x will remove all the additional scripts, brushes etc. you probably installed.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to your home directory, press CTRL+H, then find the folder called ".gimpx.x" and delete it. This is where all of your settings are stored for your account, and this will work with most any program... Just delete the hidden folder in your home directory.

Comment: It didn't work previous time but now it works. I don't know what I did wrong but thank you for that. Now I have it again!

Answer (score 3):

Deleting sessionrc is required in Gimp 2.8.

Comment: You could be right, but you should include to your answer how and what exactly is to be deleted.

Comment: `rm  ~/.gimp-2.8/sessionrc`